.NET 8 converts uppercase Turkish 'I' to lowercase 'i' instead of 'ı'"
I'm working with .NET 8 and encountering an issue with character conversion in Turkish text. According to Turkish language rules, when converting uppercase 'I' to lowercase, it should become 'ı'. However, in my .NET 8 application, it converts 'İ' to 'i' instead. How can I ensure that .NET 8 handles this conversion correctly to 'ı'?
.Net 8
var toLower = "Iı".ToLower();

// Output 
// iı

.NET Framework 4.7
var toLower = "Iı".ToLower();

// Output 
// ıı


What culture is your code running under?

Your description refers to İ but your code snippets use I; is this intentional?

Looks behaving correct to me https://dotnetfiddle.net/oTSz3p

To ensure correct handling of Turkish text, you might want to use something like: var culture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR"); var toLower = "Iı".ToLower(culture); - but it would probably help to read up about .NET culture handling first.

.NET works correctly and the culture is relevant. The .NET 8 results mean Thread.CurrentCulture isn't Turkish. Not only can this be replicated, the Turkish I is the best known example of the differences between cultures in Unicode. In fact, the actual letter is the dotless I, which is used by other cultures, including The I letter is the plain old I found in the 7-bit US-ASCII range. ToLower() uses the thread's default culture.

@PanagiotisKanavos - FYI your link is incorrect here the correct one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotless_I

Use CultureInfo("tr-TR") in .NET 8 for the conversion.
Refer the code below:
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var turkishCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
        var text = "Iı";
        var toLower = text.ToLower(turkishCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(toLower); // Output: ıı
    }
}


Refer to the working .netfiddle here


Or just use Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR"). The current culture obviously isn't tr-TR and needs to be set

Implementation of these two methods in .NetFemeWork and .Net
similar as shown below, both of which use CurrentCulture
in .Net
 public string ToLower(CultureInfo? culture)
 {
     CultureInfo cult = culture ?? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
     return cult.TextInfo.ToLower(this);
 }

in .NetFrameWork
public string ToLower()
{
    return ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}

If you want to explicitly mention which culture to use, the code will be as follows
 var toLower = "Iı".ToLower(new CultureInfo("tr-TR"));


Or just use Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR").
